# Python Finding the newest file in a folder using glob

Tags: python, glob

I am using the following code to try and find the most up to date file in a folder.
However i am getting a funny character back
The actual file is called `G:\\foo\\example - YTD.zip`

```
# Identify the file with the latest create timestamp
list_of_files = glob.glob('G:\\foo\\\\*.zip')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

latest_file
'G:\\foo\\example � YTD.zip'
```

Can anyone help?
I am a complete Python newbie so appreciate this could be a rookie question

Comment: Seems like the hyphen isn't a hyphen but something else.

Comment: Is there a way to somehow replace it with the python equivalent of string_replace?

Comment: You can try to rename it using `os.system` with a UNIX mv command, but perhaps you would want to do this via your OS instead of python since this might be a one-off?

Comment: Hi @astrochun, Thank you very much for your reply. It isn't my file so i cant change the name. A new file gets posted once a week to a sharepoint. Im not sure why `–` seems to be converted to the question mark sign

Comment: So what are you trying to do with your code? You found the latest file that is updated.

Comment: Hi @astrochun, this doesnt find the latest file as the latest file is `G:\\foo\\example - YTD.zip` while the file brought back from the script is `G:\\foo\\example � YTD.zip`. I basicaly want to open it and read it into a dataframe. If i apply `latest_file.encode("UTF-8")`, i get `\xe2\x80\x93` instead of my `-` or my `�`

Comment: This question needs some rework. @JohnSmith please copy/paste the filename as seen by you in the question. It might contain some strange characters.

Comment: Hi @fluxens, The file name i see when i look at this in windows explorer is `example - YTD.zip`. When i run my code I see `example � YTD.zip`

Comment: @JohnSmith  you could use the chardet library to identify the encoding and start from there. As for the reason why this strange encoding is applied to your string might be a different question.